# getting these console errors and really have no idea to solve it

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd, console

`Uncaught TypeError: this.toggleElements.toggleSingle is not a function`

- at Object.match (app.js:1004)
- at QueryHandler.on (enquire.js:100)
- at enquire.js:214
- at each (enquire.js:38)
- at MediaQuery.assess (enquire.js:213)
- at MediaQueryList.MediaQuery.listener (enquire.js:150)

**Edit:**

i have added this script in app.js and these errors are not showing but now i am facing this `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` app.js:1011 after changing code at app.js:1004

```
match: function () {
    if(this.toggleElements.length > 0){
        this.toggleElements.toggleSingle();
    }
},
unmatch: function () {
    if(this.toggleElements.length > 0){
        this.toggleElements.toggleSingle({destruct: true});
        }
    });
```

My noconflict.js already contain `$`

Comment: Are you loading two different versions of jQuery? or maybe prototype **and** jQuery (in which case you need to noconflict jQuery)

Comment: Can you look where this function is defined ... it should look like `toggleSingle = function (options)`

Answer (score 0):

@jscar i have added this script in app.js and these errors are not showing but now i am facing this Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) app.js:1011 after changing code at app.js:1004

```
match: function () {
    if(this.toggleElements.length > 0){
        this.toggleElements.toggleSingle();
    }
},
unmatch: function () {
    if(this.toggleElements.length > 0){
        this.toggleElements.toggleSingle({destruct: true});
        }
    });
```

my noconflict.js already contain $

Comment: @sv3n thanks... i dont have enough reputation to upvote you thats y posting as answer... thanks alotttttttttttttttttt

now after adding as you guided i am getting app.js:1003 object dont support property or method " toggle single " :(